# UITableView Not Showing Reorder Controls

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview

When I use `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt` my TableView will show the delete and reorder options, however when selecting `reorder` nothing happens.  I think I have all of the correct methods and am calling `setEditing`; is there anything else I'm missing?  Thanks!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

  let tableView = UITableView()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
    
      setupTableView()
  }

  func setupTableView() {
      tableView.frame = self.view.frame
      tableView.dataSource = self
      tableView.delegate = self
      tableView.register(CustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")
      tableView.dragInteractionEnabled = true
    
      self.view.addSubview(tableView)
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return 8
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
      cell.backgroundColor = .gray
      cell.showsReorderControl = true

      return cell
  }

  override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
      super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
      self.tableView.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
      let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "delete") { (action, view, completion) in
          tableView.reloadData()
          completion(true)
      }
    
      let reorderAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "reorder") { (action, view, completion) in
          tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
          completion(true)
      }

      return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction, reorderAction])
   }
}

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
 
}
```

Result after swiping:

[image]

After selecting `reorder`:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few observations:

1. You are not going to get the reorder controls if you do not implement `tableView(_:moveRowAt:to:)`, e.g., assuming you had a model which was an array called `objects`, you could do the following:

   ```swift
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
       let object = objects.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
       objects.insert(object, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
   }
   ```
2. The `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt` is probably not the right place to put a “reorder” command. Part of the reason is that once the table view is in edit mode and you tap on the ⛔️, the trailing actions show up, and “reorder” does not make sense in that context. E.g., here I am tapping on ⛔️ and I see the confusing actions.

   [image]

   I would suggest only adding “delete” as the trailing action. That way, you (a) get only “delete” if you tap on ⛔️ in `isEditing` mode, but also (b) get the stand-alone swipe action, too.
3. You cannot initiate `isEditing` from the trailing swipe actions (and, as discussed above, I do not think you want to, anyway). So, if you do not have “reorder” in the trailing swipe actions, you need some other method to enter edit mode. E.g., above, I added an “edit” button to the navigation bar that toggles `isEditing`:

   ```swift
   @IBAction func didTapEdit(_ sender: Any) {
       tableView.isEditing.toggle()
   }
   ```

   Then, you can keep the swipe to delete functionality, but when you tap on edit button, you have the tap on ⛔️ to delete functionality (plus the handles for reordering because we added `tableView(_:moveRowAt:to:)` as outlined in step one, above):

   [image]
4. Another way to achieve reordering is to just allow drag and drop within the table view where you can long-press on a row and then drag it:

   [image]

   This is enabled by setting `dragInteractionEnabled` and `dropDelegate`:

   ```swift
   class ViewController: UIViewController {
       @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

       let formatter: NumberFormatter = {
           let formatter = NumberFormatter()
           formatter.numberStyle = .spellOut
           return formatter
       }()

       private var objects: [Foo] = ...

       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()

           ...

           tableView.dragInteractionEnabled = true
           tableView.dropDelegate = self
       }
   }

   // MARK: - UITableViewDataSource

   extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource { ... }

   // MARK: - UITableViewDelegate

   extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
           let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "delete") { [weak self] action, view, completion in
               self?.objects.remove(at: indexPath.row)
               tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .middle)
               completion(true)
           }

           return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])
       }

       // This is used if table view is in `isEditing` mode and by `UITableViewDropDelegate`

       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
           let object = objects.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
           objects.insert(object, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
       }
   }

   // MARK: - UITableViewDropDelegate

   extension ViewController: UITableViewDropDelegate {
       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, dropSessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession, withDestinationIndexPath destinationIndexPath: IndexPath?) -> UITableViewDropProposal {
           guard
               session.items.count == 1,                            // Accept only one drag item ...
               tableView.hasActiveDrag                              // ... from within this table view
           else {
               return UITableViewDropProposal(operation: .cancel)
           }

           return UITableViewDropProposal(operation: .move, intent: .insertAtDestinationIndexPath)
       }

       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, performDropWith coordinator: UITableViewDropCoordinator) {
           guard let destinationIndexPath = coordinator.destinationIndexPath else { return }

           for item in coordinator.items {
               if let sourceIndexPath = item.sourceIndexPath {
                   DispatchQueue.main.async {
                       tableView.moveRow(at: sourceIndexPath, to: destinationIndexPath)
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Clearly, if you were going to enable drag from this app to others, you would add `UITableViewDragDelegate` conformance here, and make your model objects conform to `NSItemProviderReading` and `NSItemProviderWriting`. But the above should be sufficient for dragging and dropping to reorder within a `UITableView`.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer and guidance!  I wasn't aware `isEditing` couldn't be initiated from the trailing swipe action; that's really helpful.